# Excel pdf exporting - Run-time error '5" in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, runtime

I've developed code that has been functional for the last 3 years on multiple company computers, all running Windows 7 and Office 2007.  A new round of lease renewals has occurred and one of my employees has been given a machine running Windows 10 and Office 2007.  We are all running different versions of Acrobat Pro.

I am having a problem with a macro that's in my Excel workbook that outputs a PDF whenever a user clicks on a button embedded in the sheet.  Basically, the sequence is:

1. User presses button.
2. Spreadsheet recalculates (F9).
3. User is prompted where to save the file (filename is already prepopulated based upon a cell in the sheet).
4. User selects save and pdf is saved.
5. Pop-up box prompts user whether the new pdf should be printed to the local printer.  If "yes", print, else don't.
6. End sequence.

Here's the code:

```
'Code for creating the PDF document and subsequently displaying it

Dim fnamePDF As String
With ActiveSheet
fnamePDF = .Range("H11").Value
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fnamePDF, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End With
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fnamePDF` return?

Comment: you didnt mention what is the actual error you are facing ?

Comment: I just ran your code & it has no issues... In variable fnamePDF I only wrote the name of the file.